# Dynamic Creation Of Pandas Column for Complex Structure with Array of Jsons

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

***TL:DR; Given an array of arrays of JSON inside a dict, I want to split each array of JSON Object into 2 Columns while re-using the already created columns for the previous array!***

Hello,

I have an array of dicts in python which are a combination of YT Analytics Response. The array (after my processing) looks like that:

```
[{
 "Video ID": "XJasdj1231",
 "Video Title": "Hey, It is ME!",
 "Video Views": 21,110,
 "Video Tags": [{"abc":0},{"sad":0},{"happy":0}],
 "Video Search Tags": [{"jih": 9}, {"XA":3}]
 "Non Search Tags": [{"Messi":12}, {"Cr7":3}]
}, {
 "Video ID": "SADSAD",
 "Video Title": "Nope",
 "Video Views": 120,000,
 "Video Tags": [{"CSA":0},{"ASDF":0},{"GAS":0}, {"Liquid":0}, {"Informa":0}],
 "Video Search Tags": [{"jih": 9}, {"XA":3}, {"Xia":3}, {"OSAD":3}]
 "Non Search Tags": [{"Messi":12}, {"Cr7":3}, {"Mo":3}, {"Mera":3}, {"Micko":3}]
}]
```

So, each JSON object represents a unique video. As show, the first 3 attributes (Video ID, Video Title and views) are relatively easy to convert into PD Dataframe using the `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ARRAY)` function.

PS: Used quick notations just to make it shorter

This function if used on the whole Array it will produce output like that:

```
ID           Title              Views    Tags          Search Tags    Non-search tags
 
XJasdj1231  Hey, It is ME!      XXXX    [[{"abc":0},     SAME LIKE VIDEO TAGS
                                       {"sad":0},
                                       {"happy":0}],

SADSAD        Nope              XXXX    SAME LIKE VIDEO TAGS    SAME LIKE VIDEO TAGS
```

As you see the whole array of JSON is pasted in the cell. What I would like to achieve is a dynamic creation of columns.

For each tag in `"Video Tags": [{"abc":0},{"sad":0},{"happy":0}]` I want to create the columns like that

```
Tag 1 Views 1 Tag 2 Views 2 Tag 3 Views 3 ......Tag X Views X
abc    0       sad    0      Happy  0
```

Each JSON object of the array is split into Tag {NUM} Views {SAME NUM}

The same for `Video Search Tags & Non Search Tags` With exception that I will make the column names

```
Search 1 Views 1 .... Search X Views X
```

Key thing here is that, not all videos have the same number of tags, some videos will have 3 or 30!

So, for example, if the first video had 30 tags and I created 30 columns for it with namings Tag 30 Views 30. And the second video had 10 tags only, I want it to be assigned in the first 10 Tags and 10 Views columns that were already made.

If the third video had 40 tags, I want it to re-use the first 30 and create an additional 10!

I thought about using `PD.data_frame.serie` but I stumbled upon the re-use columns feature.

Any ideas how can I achieve something like that?

Sorry for the long post!

Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a `df` from your `dict` as you did. Then iterate through the rows and assign the columns dynamically. After finishing, remove the original column name from `df`. Please check the code below:

```
dict = [{
         "Video ID": "XJasdj1231",
         "Video Title": "Hey, It is ME!",
         "Video Views": 21110,
         "Video Tags": [{"abc":0},{"sad":0},{"happy":0}],
         "Video Search Tags": [{"jih": 9}, {"XA":3}],
         "Non Search Tags": [{"Messi":12}, {"Cr7":3}]
        }, {
         "Video ID": "SADSAD",
         "Video Title": "Nope",
         "Video Views": 120000,
         "Video Tags": [{"CSA":0},{"ASDF":0},{"GAS":0}, {"Liquid":0}, {"Informa":0}],
         "Video Search Tags": [{"jih": 9}, {"XA":3}, {"Xia":3}, {"OSAD":3}],
         "Non Search Tags": [{"Messi":12}, {"Cr7":3}, {"Mo":3}, {"Mera":3}, {"Micko":3}]
        }]

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

def dynamic_cols(df, col, tag_nm):
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for i, tag_dict in enumerate(row[col], 1):
            for tag in tag_dict:
                views = tag_dict[tag]

                # define column names
                tag_colnm = f"{tag_nm} { i }"
                views_colnm = f"Views { i }"

                # set tag and views columns
                df.at[index, tag_colnm] = tag
                df.at[index, views_colnm] = views

    # remove column from df
    df = df[df.columns.difference([col])]

    return df

df = dynamic_cols(df, "Video Tags", "Tag")
df = dynamic_cols(df, "Video Search Tags", "Search")
df = dynamic_cols(df, "Non Search Tags", "Search")
```

Result:

```
        Search 1    Search 2    Search 3    Search 4    Search 5    Tag 1    Tag 2    Tag 3    Tag 4    Tag 5    Video ID    Video Title       Video Views    Views 1    Views 2    Views 3    Views 4    Views 5
--  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -------  -------  -------  -------  -------  ----------  --------------  -------------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------  ---------
0  Messi       Cr7         nan         nan         nan         abc      sad      happy    nan      nan      XJasdj1231  Hey, It is ME!          21110         12          3          0        nan        nan
1  Messi       Cr7         Mo          Mera        Micko       CSA      ASDF     GAS      Liquid   Informa  SADSAD      Nope                   120000         12          3          3          3          3
```

---

**EDIT 1:** added Views columns + dynamic col. creation in function for the sake of reusability.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! This really helped! Can you tell me how to change it though to be

search 1 Views 1 search 2 views 2, etc. ? (Search views after each other for each index)

Answer (score 0):

Sample Data:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([{
     "Video ID": "XJasdj1231",
     "Video Title": "Hey, It is ME!",
     "Video Views": 21110,
     "Video Tags": [{"abc":0},{"sad":0},{"happy":0}],
     "Video Search Tags": [{"jih": 9}, {"XA":3}],
     "Non Search Tags": [{"Messi":12}, {"Cr7":3}]
    }, {
     "Video ID": "SADSAD",
     "Video Title": "Nope",
     "Video Views": 120000,
     "Video Tags": [{"CSA":0},{"ASDF":0},{"GAS":0}, {"Liquid":0}, {"Informa":0}],
     "Video Search Tags": [{"jih": 9}, {"XA":3}, {"Xia":3}, {"OSAD":3}],
     "Non Search Tags": [{"Messi":12}, {"Cr7":3}, {"Mo":3}, {"Mera":3}, {"Micko":3}]
    }])
    df.head()
```

Solution:

1. Generate empty dataframe with enough `Tags, Views` columns. For this purpose the length of all lists is read
2. For each index of the dataframe get all Tags. By `explode()` pandas flatten the original list.
3. Extract the information of each item of tags and write it to the dataframe

I was not succesfull with eliminating the for loops at the moment - thus there is probably a more elegant approach.

Code:

```
maxTags=max(df['Video Tags'].apply(lambda x: len(x)))
df_tags=pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=["{0} {1}".format(title, num+1) for num in range (maxTags) for title in ['Tag', 'Views']])

for idx in df.index:
    tags=df['Video Tags'].explode().loc[idx]
    for i,tag in enumerate(tags):
        name=list(tag.keys())[0]
        df_tags.loc[idx, "Views {}".format(i+1)]=tag[name]
        df_tags.loc[idx, "Tag {}".format(i+1)]=name
```